# HIGHCHARTS: Filling area above line with color area representing contribution to line values

Tags: highcharts

I have a step-wise descending line. Each step is a milestone responsible for the change in the line's value and we want to be able to color the area for the step across the chart to show the contribution of each event.

Like the orange, green and purple bands in this image here (ignore the annotations):

[image]

Is this possible with Highcharts? The bands would go above the dotted green line in this chart:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please check `plotBands` and `plotLines` property/object. here is a snippet explaining how to use them in chart.

```
yAxis: {
  plotBands: [{
        from: 125,
        to: 175,
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2)',
        width: 1,
        label: {
            formatter: function () {
                return 'plot band';
            }
        }
    }],
    plotLines: [{
        color: 'red',
        width: 2,
        value: 100,
        label: {
            text: '100 Plot line',
            style: {
                color: 'blue',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        }
    },{
        color: 'green',
        width: 2,
        value: 50,
        label: {
            text: '50 Plot line',
            style: {
                color: 'blue',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        }
    },{
        color: 'blue',
        width: 2,
        value: 200,
        label: {
            text: '200 Plot line',
            style: {
                color: 'red',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        }
    }]
},
```

check out this link for [PlotLine & Bands](https://jsfiddle.net/0uw5zxfy/)

Comment: This doesn't accomplish the goal, as we don't want the bands to span the entire length of the chart but only the area above and to the right of the line, per the image in the example.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution to achieve the wanted result is using the polygon series.

Demo: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/polygon

Comment: Hmmm... Polygons might be the way to go, I have also been also looking at area charts: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-basic do you have experience with those, could they work?

Comment: @noob, notice that the area series renders some area from the 0 to the set values, but your case seems to be able to render in the particular range, not the start from the 0.